# Possible missed verb in the sentence

Tags: phrase-meaning

I wonder if the word "credibility" highlighted in bold below should follow a verb like "lent" or "gave".

My understanding of the sentence as it is is that researchers should "attend to credibility to experienced clinicians", which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Here is the original text extracted from *The Art and Science of Psychotherapy*.

> It suggests that RCTs could be used in far more effective ways if
> researchers attended to aspects of experimental design and
> **credibility** to experienced clinicians such as using scientifically appropriate control conditions (most importantly, clinicians in the
> community attempting to do their best work) and patient samples
> resembling those seen in the community seeking treatment for the kinds
> of problems that lead most patients to present for treatment.

Comment: Yes, something is missing here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a comment which is too big ...

The Sentence is too long with much ambiguity. That is in addition to the missing word(s) near credibility and elsewhere ...

**Here is "One Possible Parsing" , with embedded editorial comments** :

It suggests that RCTs could be used in far more effective ways if researchers attended to "aspects of (A) experimental design and (B) credibility to [[change this "to" to "among"]] experienced clinicians" such as [[ by ]] using (1) scientifically appropriate control conditions (most importantly, clinicians in the community attempting to do their best work) and [[ by using ]] (2) patient samples resembling those seen in the community seeking treatment for the kinds of problems that lead most patients to present for treatment.

**Here is "One More Possible Parsing" , with embedded editorial comments** :

It suggests that RCTs could be used in far more effective ways if researchers (A) attended to aspects of experimental design and (B) [[ gave ]] credibility to experienced clinicians such as [[ change this "such as" to "by" ]] using (1) scientifically appropriate control conditions (most importantly, clinicians in the community attempting to do their best work) and [[ by using ]] (2) patient samples resembling those seen in the community seeking treatment for the kinds of problems that lead most patients to present for treatment.

**Sentence is too complicated and ambiguous.

Even with grammatical corrections, the meaning may be hard to Parse.

Better to rewrite in shorter unambiguous sentences.**